# PHP Fatal error: Class 'OAuth' not found in /var/www/html/twitters/TwitterAutoReply.php on line 24

Tags: php, twitter

I was setting up a Twitter auto reply bot on my VPS. When I ran the PHP script it gave me an error. Yes, obviously I installed the PECL OAuth extension, added the code to the php.ini file & even checked it to see if it was enabled by creating a phpinfo.php file. Still, nothing.

So I'm really confused here. I even rebooted the server & restarted apache but with no success. So what should I do? Here's the output when I run the script:

> PHP Fatal error:  Class 'OAuth' not found in
>   /var/www/html/twitters/TwitterAutoReply.php on line 24
>   root@Graffocp:/var/www/html/twitters#

Thanks for your help :)

Comment: Posting the code for `TwitterAutoReply.php` would help you get a response faster. :)

Comment: how is said script being "ran"?

Comment: In response to Janaka: Here's the full code in a pastebin :) http://pastebin.com/TAANfauF